# What is hacklocaledir.so?

Tags: macos

While exploring my Macbook's directories, I stumbled on the file mentioned in title, located at 'Macintosh HD/opt/local/lib/hacklocaledir.so'

To me as a user generally uninformed about folder structures, it sounds suspicious, but I would rather find out what it is before deleting the file.

Other files in the folder include 'libGLEW.1.5.1.dylib', 'libGLEW.1.5.dylib' and 'libGLEW.dylib'. I do not recall explicitly installing any of the mentioned files.

Should I be worried, or are these files benign?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

hacklocaldir.so is a **provider** of the package help2man, a tool for automatically generating simple manual pages from program output.

> It is intended to provide an easy way for software authors to include
>   a manual page in their distribution without having to maintain that
>   document.
>
> Given a program which produces resonably standard --help and --version
>   outputs, help2man will attempt to re-arrange that output into
>   something which resembles a manual page.

Within help2man, hacklocaledir.so is also a **shared library** (/usr/lib/hacklocaledir.so).

Check https://www.rpmfind.net/linux/rpm2html/search.php?query=hacklocaledir.so for more information.

Comment: I never personally installed the 'help2man' package on my machine - could it have been done automatically during installation of some other software?

I'm still a bit suspicious, a file with the word 'hack' in its name doesn't sound exactly harmless..